# Add elements of two list of dictionaries based on a key value pair match

Tags: python, list

Given n lists with m dictionaries as their elements, I would like to produce a new list, with a joined set of dictionaries.

```
l1 = [{"index":'a', "b":2,'c':9}, {"index":'b', "b":3,"c":5}, {"index":'c', "b":8,"c":8}]
l2 = [{"index":'a', "b":4,'c':8}, {"index":'b', "b":9,"c":10},{"index":None, "b":11,"c":10}]
```

I would like to produce a joined list:

```
l3 = [{"index":'a', "b":6, "c":17}, 
     {"index":'b', "b":12, "c":15}, 
     {"index":'c', "b":8, "c":8},
     {"index":None, "b":11,"c":10}]
```

I have a method that can merge the two lists. But as you can see above, I also wish to add the elements.

```
def merge_lists(l1, l2, key):
merged = {}
for item in l1+l2:
  if item[key] in merged:
    merged[item[key]].update(item)
  else:
    merged[item[key]] = item
return [val for (_, val) in merged.items()]

l3 = merge_lists(l1,l2,'index')
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

Comment: Will dicts with the same `index` always be at the same position in the list? If no, should they still be merged?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Counter` for something like this pretty easily...

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def merge_lists(l1, l2):
    d = defaultdict(Counter)
    for sdict in l1 + l2:
        counter = Counter(sdict)
        d[counter.pop('index')] += counter    

    lists = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        result = dict(v)
        result['index'] = k
        lists.append(result)
    return lists

l1 = [{"index":'a', "b":2,'c':9}, {"index":'b', "b":3,"c":5}, {"index":'c', "b":8,"c":8}]
l2 = [{"index":'a', "b":4,'c':8}, {"index":'b', "b":9,"c":10},{"index":None, "b":11,"c":10}]
print(merge_lists(l1, l2))
```

The great thing about adding `Counter` instances is that it pretty much just does what you expect.  If one counter doesn't have the key, it adds nothing to the sum, but if both counters have the given key, then their values are added and used as the resultant value at that key.

---

Note that the order of the merged lists is arbitrary (based on the ordering of the `defaultdict`).  If you need to preserve order in some way, you can either `sort` after the fact or create a default ordered dict which will preserve the order based on when the `index` was first seen in `l1` or `l2`:

```
class DefaultOrderedDict(collections.OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self, default_factory, *args, **kwargs):
        self.default_factory = default_factory
        super(DefaultOrderedDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = self.default_factory()
        return self[key]
```

(There are more "complete" default ordered dicts floating around on ActiveState and StackOverflow, but this simple one *should* work for your problem at hand)